# How to check Oracle column values are all the same for a specific ID?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to figure out the best way to determine, for a specific ID within an Oracle 11g table that has 5 columns and say 100 rows against this ID, if all the column values are the same for these five columns.

For example:

Table Name: **TABLE_DATA**

Columns:

```
TD_ID   ID      COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4    COL5
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1       1       1       0       3       2       0
2       1       1       0       3       2       0
3       1       1       0       3       2       0
4       1       1       0       3       2       0
5       1       1       0       3       2       0
6       1       1       0       3       2       0
```

So based on the above example which is just showing 6 rows for now against the ID:1, I want to check that for all COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4 and COL5 values where ID = 1, tell me if all the values are the same from the very first row right down to the last – **if so, then return ‘Y’ else return ‘N’**.

Given the above example, the result would be ‘Y’ but for instance, if TD_ID = 5 and COL3 = 4 then the result would be ‘N’, as all the column values are not the same, i.e.:

```
TD_ID   ID      COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4    COL5
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1       1       1       0       3       2       0
2       1       1       0       3       2       0
3       1       1       0       3       2       0
4       1       1       0       3       2       0
5       1       1       0       4       2       0
6       1       1       0       3       2       0
```

I’m just not sure what the fastest approach to determine this is, as the table I am looking at may have more than 2000 rows within the table for a specific ID.

Comment: That `TD_ID` is the real pain. Without it, you could do some simple set operations and save yourself the pain of listing out every column. With it, I'm pretty sure you have to list every column explicitly.

Comment: @jeremytwfortune could you pls elaborate with examples re:simple set operations if the TD_ID was not there. Thanks.

Comment: Sure. `select case when count(1) = 1 then 'Y' else 'N' end from (select distinct * from td where id = 1) foo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if the following is fast enough for you:

```
SELECT ID, CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END As "Result"
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID, COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5
      FROM Table_Data) dist
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 3):

You may also try this :

```
Select ID 
, case when count(distinct COL1 || COL2 || COL3 || COL4 || COL5) > 1 
  then 'N'
  else 'Y' end RESULT
From TABLE_DATA
Group by id;
```

In this way you group by id and counts how many distinct combination are there.
If only 1 , so all the rows have the same set of values, otherwise it don't.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little query, you might wanna try out (eventually, you just could try figuring out a better `MINUS` statement for you):

```
SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN (  -- select count of records from a subquery
            SELECT 
              COUNT(1) 
            FROM
            ( -- select all rows where id = 1
              SELECT
                td.col1
                ,td.col2
                ,td.col3
                ,td.col4
                ,td.col5
              FROM
                table_data td
              WHERE
                td.id = 1
              MINUS -- substract the first row of the table with id = 1
              SELECT
                td.col1
                ,td.col2
                ,td.col3
                ,td.col4
                ,td.col5
              FROM
                table_data td
              WHERE
                td.id = 1
                AND ROWNUM = 1
            )
        ) = 0 -- check if subquery's count equals 0
        AND EXISTS (  -- and exists at least 1 row in the table with id = 1
          SELECT
            1
          FROM
            table_data td
          WHERE
            td.id = 1
            AND ROWNUM = 1
        ) THEN 'Y' 
    ELSE 'N' 
  END AS equal
FROM
  dual
```